# Find Identifier in Semantic Model

Tags: c#, roslyn

Supposing I have a source file that looks like this:

```
public class FieldReference
{
    int field;

    public FieldReference()
    {
        field = 1;
    }
}
```

I am using a SyntaxRewriter to visit all of the identifiers in this file. In the VisitIdentifierName method, I want to look up the identifier in the semantic model, in order to discover if an identifier refers to a member of the current class.

This is what I have so far:

```
public override SyntaxNode VisitIdentifierName(IdentifierNameSyntax node)
{
    SemanticModel model = this.compilation.GetSemanticModel(this.src);
    // ?? look up identifier in compilation here ??
    return base.VisitIdentifierName(node);
}
```

However I can't find away to look up the identifier in the symantic model - there is no overload of the SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol method that accepts an IdentifierNameSyntax.

Any idea how I should do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo` on the expression (in this particular case the `IdentifierNameSyntax`).

`GetDeclaredSymbol` is for going from the declaration point (`int field;` above) to a symbol.  To perform the compiler's binding logic and see what symbol a particular expression binds to, use `GetSymbolInfo`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, not sure how I overlooked that. All just very new to me I guess!

Comment: hmm, this seems broken in the current preview version of Roslyn. See the samples project => ConvertToAutoPropertyCS => Inside the PropertyRewriter => VisitFieldDeclaration(FieldDeclarationSyntax field) There is no way to get the symbol for the field parameter.

Comment: Because a field declaration can declare more than one symbol, you need to actually use the VariableDeclaratorSyntax.